# Why is a row with a value NULL still choosen when there is a value of 1 in the column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which has a column in which some rows have the value 1. This is because i want use a query like "where column !='1' " to select all rows which do not have a 1 (the character 1) in this column/field.

Strangely, when i query the table like:

```
select * from table where column !='1'
```

all the rows where there is NULL in this same column are also treated as if there would be a 1 (character 1) in the column.

According to my DB knowledge the character 1 and NULL are definitely not the same and should not be treated the same in a query!?

I know today PDO is recommended but this is not a internet accessible web application but just a local db in which i sort some quite unimportant data. Once when i have time i will rewrite it with PDO but not at the moment.

Thanks for any help
Markus

Comment: well... hard to debug... but can you change your query to: `select * from table where col IS NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `IS NULL` to your query.

`select * from table WHERE column <> '1' OR column IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

When the column's value is `NULL` then the condition is:

```
WHERE NULL !='1'
```

and since any comparison to `NULL` has as result the value `NULL` then the condition is:

```
WHERE NULL
```

which clearly is **not**

```
WHERE TRUE
```

so that row is not returned.
What you can do if you want `NULL`s in the results is to explicitly include the condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE column !=' '1' OR column IS NULL
```